# How can I grant datareader to a sql role?

Tags: sql-server, permissions, datareader, role

Is it possible to grant the datareader privileges to a SQL Server Database Role rather than a User?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the [GRANT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178569.aspx) command.

```
USE DBNAME;
GRANT SELECT TO RoleName;
GO
```

Comment: Also, it might not let you grant to the built-in roles ("db_*") - at least, it won't through the UI.  But you can grant to roles that you create.

Answer (score 3):

You could add your (user defined) database role to db_datareader as a role member, using the UI.

Comment: Through the GUI, view the properties of the Database Role 'db_datareader'.  On the General tab, under 'Members of this role:', click 'Add...'.  This dialog allows selection of either users or other database roles.